# Checking if any values in object are not null

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```js
err = {
  "content-type": null,
  phone: null,
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
  email: null,
  website: null,
  supplier: null
}

console.log(Object.keys(err).some(key => key !== null))
```

I learnt about the `.some` function from stackoverflow, but this is returning true.  All the values are null, so I would expect it to return false.

I just need a way to check if any of the values are not null, then I know there are errors in the form.

Comment: `Object.values(err).filter(v => v === null).length === 0`

Comment: [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) will return the key elements of an object, you need to use [`Objec.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Object.values()` method to get an array of the object's values.
Use the `Array.every()` method to iterate over the array.
Check if each `value` is equal to null.
The `every()` method will return true if all values are null.

```js
const err = {
  "content-type": null,
  phone: null,
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
  email: null,
  website: null,
  supplier: null
}

const result = Object.values(err).every(value => {
  if (value === null) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
});

console.log(result);
```

[Reference](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-check-if-all-object-properties-are-null)

Comment: Thanks, yeah that works.  Actually phpstorm simplified the inside the function to be just `return value === null` which works just as well.

Comment: @RichardBridge phpstorm could have gone tad further too, seen as your using arrow functions -> `value => value === null`

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using `Array#some` here.

But you need to use `Object.values` (not `Object.keys`).

```js
const err = {
  "content-type": null,
  phone: null,
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
  email: null,
  website: null,
  supplier: null
}

// Note use of Object.values (not Object.keys)
console.log(Object.values(err).some(key => key !== null))
```